# Como mostrar el speudo class :after detrás de su padre

Tags: css, css3

Busco que el circulo en el speudo class se muestre por detras del elemento padre. Tengo este código en css

```css
div{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.point {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 1;*/
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #2fa7e6;
  background: white;
}

.point::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    background: #fff;
    content: " ";
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span class="point"></span>
</div>
```

resultado esperado (solo los circulos).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: .point y point:after son 2 circulos.  point:after tapa el circulo .point si le quitas al .point::after el background veras el otro circulo... pero necesito el background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quitale el `z-index` al padre y ponle `display: block` para que se aplique el width / height

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.point {
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: 1;*/
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px blue;
  background: white;
}

.point::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #2fa7e6;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="point"></span></div>
```

Comment: Funcionó, pero surge otro problema y es que ".point::after" se pone detrás de los padres de .point.

Comment: puedes poner el código? para ver que tienen los padres de .point

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta con la solucion que me comentaste

Comment: Una solución que veo entonces es intercambiar los circulos del .point y del ::after, he actualizado la respuesta con como quedarian los estilos.